# Uniform convergence (similar to Dini's theorem, but different)

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f_n(x)$ assumes its maximum on $[a,b]$, and $f_n\geq f_{n+1}\to 0$. Show that $f_n$ is uniformly convergent to $0$.

This is analogous to Dini's theorem. However, we do not know the continuity of $f$. How can we prove this statement? I have checked the proof of Dini's theorem; however, I could not get across the difficulties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is false. Take $[a,b]=[0,1]$ and
$$
f_n(x) = \begin{cases}
  1 & \text{if $x \in (0,1/n]$}\\
  0 & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$

Clearly $\max f_n =1$ (hence there is not uniform convergence). Moreover $f_{n+1} \le f_n$ since the sequence of sets $(0,1/n]$ is decreasing. Moreover $f_n(0) = 0 \to 0$ and for $x>0$ one has $f_n(x)=0$ for all $n>1/x$ hence again $f_n\to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

If $\sup_{x \in [a,b]}|f_{n}(x)| =: l_{n}$ for all $n \geq 1$, and if there is some $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $l_{n} \geq \varepsilon$ for infinitely many $n$, then, by the assumption that $f_{n}$ attains maximum on $[a,b]$ for each $n \geq 1$, there are infinitely many $n$ such that $f_{n}(x) \geq \varepsilon$ for some $x \in [a,b]$, contradicting the assumption that $f_{n} \to 0.$